# Create multiple subscription keys for one API in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, apim

I am looking for a fast victory to protect an API with multiple subscription keys, in order to assign them to different providers and allow access individually. I know that Oauth2 could be the best fit for this goal but, multiple subscription keys could be an option?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure [API Management aka APIM](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/products/api-management) to secure your API. With this you have several options.

You can [create subscription keys](https://www.serverlessnotes.com/docs/securing-api-access-with-subscription-keys) for each consumer setting what they can access. This is quicker and easier to set up for both sides.

Alternatively, if your consumers can, you can [set up an OAuth flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad) which is more secure.

Which you choose will depend on your situation.